No peaches on peach tree this year
Last year in august we moved here and there were tons of peaches on and around the peach tree. Then over the next year some branches got damaged and now half the tree has no leaves at all. The leafy side has no peach blossoms either. What can I do to hope for peaches next year ? Trim off the dead branches ? How ?

Where are you located? What's your hardiness zone?

I highly suspect it hasn't got the sufficient chill hours necessary for peach to bloom and flower. What is the variety of peach and is it suited for your zone/ climate?

Based on the complete lack of location data, this is a random guess; Based on the question stating they moved in last August, it's highly unlikely that the prior owner(s) documented what variety of peach tree was planted for the benefit of future owners.

@Ecnerwal True. But I stated based on my personal experiences with peaches. That happened to me as well last year. I checked on with horticulture experts from the region where I got peaches from. Turns out they did had problems pertaining to chill hours. Also, owing to the previous year being El niño year it was understandable.

Apart from the damage and dead branches, it's not unusual for peaches (and other fruit trees) that are not aggressively thinned to get into a biennial bearing habit, where the large fruit crop exhausts the tree's resources, and it then takes a year off from fruiting and recovers before trying again.
External events can also cause no fruit, such as late frosts or freezes killing the flower buds, or lack of pollinators causing them not to be pollinated.
Pruning dead branches is a normal and well-documented part of tree care. Whether you need a chainsaw, a hand saw, loppers or pruning shears rather depends on the size of branch. Where to correctly cut should be based on referring to some of the extensive documentation so you understand the importance of the "branch collar" in healing the wound, and don't leave too long of a stub, or cut off the branch collar and impede healing. It's often best to make two cuts - one leaving a bit of a stub, so if the branch breaks at the cut it does not damaged the healthy tree, and then one where the stub is shortened without so much weight hanging off the point being cut.

Anecdotal fact (of pasts): when a person knew he should live a place next year, such person would prune plants to maximize this year production, not long term one (so not trying to reduce the biennial bearing habit of the answer). Possibly combined with rain/cold during flowering time and you may get not fruit this year. Take into account when pruning it next year.

I would recommend fertilizing them (according to recommendations for peach trees), if you haven't. Fertilization really seems to help fruiting, especially if you have soil that isn't ideal for your tree.
